# Need help in array output

Tags: java

I need some help on this array to show the output, but it seem like doesn't work what I expect.

```
public static void main(String[] args){


            String[][] record = {
                {"abc","123","cbv"},
                {"efg","456","cbb"},
                {"hij","321","ggb"},
                {"xyz","A4","ghy"}};


            for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
                System.out.println(record[i][j]);
```

The Output show :

```
abc
123
cbv
efg
456
cbb
hij
321
ggb
xyz
A4
ghy
```

I need the output to show as :

```
abc 123 cbv
efg 456 ccb
hij 321 ggb
xyz A4 ghy
```

Answer (score 4):

You should do:

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++) {
        System.out.print(record[i][j] + " ");  // print instead of println
    }
    System.out.println();                      // println (new row)
}
```

(The inner loop which prints elements in one row should not print line-breaks.)

Or, even better, use `System.out.printf` to make sure all elements are equally wide (this example also uses for each loops):

```
for (String[] row : record) {
    for (String element : row)
        System.out.printf("%5s", element);
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output:**

```
  abc  123  cbv
  efg  456  cbb
  hij  321  ggb
  xyz   A4  ghy
```

Comment: You're welcome... If the answer resolved your issue, consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++) {
        System.out.print(record[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
for (int j=0;j<3;j++) {
    System.out.print(record[i][j] + " ");  // print instead of println

}
System.out.println();                      // println (new row)
}
```